# Chinese character to ASCII or Hexadecimal

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hex, ascii

Im struggling to covert chinese word/characters to ascii or hexadecimal and all the values I've got up until now is not what I was suppose to get.

Example of conversion is the word 手 to hex is 1534b.

Methods Ive followed till now are as below, and I got varieties of results but the one I was looking for,

I really appreciate if you can help me out on this issue,

Thanks, 
Mike

```
 - (NSString *) stringToHex:(NSString *)str{
NSUInteger len = [str length];
unichar *chars = malloc(len * sizeof(unichar));
[str getCharacters:chars];
NSMutableString *hexString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++ )
{        
    [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]]; //EDITED PER COMMENT BELOW
}
free(chars);
return hexString;}
```

and

```
const char *cString = [@"手" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

below is the similar code in Java for Android, Maybe it helps

```
    public boolean sendText(INotifiableManager manager, String text) {
       final int codeOffset = 0xf100;

       for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {


       int code = (int)c+codeOffset;


       if (! mConnection.getBoolean(manager, "SendKey", Integer.toString(code))) {


       }
```

Comment: ASCII doesn't have codepoints for these characters.  Why are you trying to use it?　　You should use UTF-8 instead (or Shift-JIS if you want to piss off everyone in the world outside of Japan).

Comment: Im trying to send it to a media box through HTML call, I have to either convert it to ascii or hex to be able to do so

Comment: The correct way to send these characters through a URL is to *percent encode* them.  See this method -> `- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` and be sure to use UTF-8, *not* ASCII.

Comment: The character `手` is Unicode character `U+6248`. In UTF-8 this is encoded as `E6898B`. What encoding gives you the desired value of `1534B`?

Comment: by using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding this word will be encoded to %E6%89%8B which is not acceptable to my needs. As I said, Im using an HTTP API call for a media box which support Ascii or hex. do u have any other ideas?

Comment: Ive made some changes to my question by adding similar method in Android app. Any helps to convert it to Objec C?

Comment: @Mike You haven't described "your needs" clearly at all.  The Java you wrote is not using ASCII either.  It appears to just be an arbitrary offset of the UTF-16 encoding.  Don't you think that information would have been helpful?

Comment: Based on the Java code, just do the same. Iterate through the `unichar` characters of the `NSString`. For each character, add your offset of `0xf100`. You'll get the same results. Just keep in mind that `unichar` isn't wide enough for this. `unichar` is only 16-bits.

Comment: By the way, I hope you understand that HTTP requests are *designed* to support the above percent encoding that I mentioned.  The reason for the percent encoding is to turn them into ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java code is just doing this:

Take each 16-bit character of the string and add 0xf100 to it.

If you do the same thing in your above Objective-C code you will get the result you want.

Comment: Sorry for the really noob question, but isn't 手 one single character?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "character."

Comment: So, based on your explanations, how can I convert my NSString in this case to the equivalent amount of 16-bit unichars?

Comment: @Mike Yes, in terms of an `NSString`, `手` is a single character.

Comment: You are already doing it in your above code by saying `chars[i]` but a better way would just be to use `characterAtIndex:` on the `NSString` object.

Comment: Dude, u just ended a misery to my life... What I did was to add 0xf100 with [Mystring characterAtIndex:i] as u said and yes I got the result I wanted... anyway, what do we call this conversion from the 手 to 1534b using this method?

Comment: You call it "arbitrary conversion" as far as I'm aware.  What's wrong with just using the plain UTF-16 encoding?

Comment: Its not of my decision, the Multimedia box that Im trying to communicate with accepts only this kind of conversion through HTTP API calls. I know there are million better ways to do this but this is the requirement of the project!